# Header Exam package

Tags: tcolorbox, exam

I am try make example header in picture exam class with minimal

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.3,frame=2pt]{02.pdf}
\end{minipage}\hfill \vspace{-3cm } 
\begin{minipage}{12.8cm} 
    \hspace{13cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}\hfill \hspace{3cm}

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        This is a \textbf{Natureza}.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        This is a \textbf{Prova Mensal}.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

How change code latex for product this example figure?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(80,135)(250,20)
\put(323.25,136.25){\psframebox[framearc=.3]{\textsc{\escola}}}
\put(323.25,114.75){\psframebox[framearc=.3]{\area}}
\put(494.5,114.75){\psframebox[framearc=.3]{Data:\quad \qquad \qquad}}
\put(590.25,114.75){\psframebox[framearc=.3]{\turma}}
\put(323.25,91.75){\psframebox[framearc=.3]{\qquad Prof: \professor \quad}}
\put(456,91.75){\psframebox[framearc=.3]{\qquad  \prova \qquad}}
\put(594.25,91.75){\psframebox[framearc=.3]{Note: \quad \qquad}}
\put(323.25,71.0){\psframebox[framearc=.3]{Student (a):\hspace{7.7cm}N\textsuperscript{0}\hspace{2cm}}}
\put(236,62.375){\psframebox[framearc=.3]{\includegraphics[scale=.28]{logo}}}
\put(456.625,102.875){\oval(452.25,105.75)[]}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```